# Powershell, registry & wildcards

Tags: powershell, registry, wildcard

I am running into two issues here.
1: Wildcards when using Get-ChildItem to get keys.
Given this code

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test_Tasks\Assets\Delete_Ex\New*'
$keys = Get-ChildItem -path:$registryPath
```

and key names of **Key**, **New Key**, **New.Key** & **New***
I get unexpected results, because Get-ChildItem uses * as a wildcard, but * is also a valid character in a Registry path. This seems rather problematic. I assume my only real option is to use -literalPath rather than -path to disable wildcards? EDIT: Nope, when I use -literalPath it doesn't even find the **New*** Key. Buggy McBuggerson? I'm on Windows 7 with PSv5, for what it's worth.

2: Wildcards when using Get-ItemProperty to get Properties.
Given this code

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test_Tasks\Assets\Delete_Ex\New*'
$properties = Get-ItemProperties -path:$registryPath
```

And property names of **New Value**, **New.Value** and **Value**
I can't get wildcards to work at all.

To be honest I worry allowing for wildcards in registry manipulations is a bit dangerous, but I would like to understand how to get it to work with both Keys and Properties in case I truly need to at some point.

Comment: Can you try escaping the asterisk with a backtick?

Comment: @gvee, that doesn't seem to work. I tried both -path and -literalPath, with single and double quotes in the variable assignment, and in all cases -path produces all three (i.e. the * is used as a wildcard) and -literalPath returns nothing at all. I am sure path names that use * or ? are edge cases, but I deal with Autodesk a lot, and I don't put anything past them. They are the reason I need to handle file system directories like **Folder.Name**!

Comment: Aha! Can you try: `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test_Tasks\Assets\Delete_Ex\New[*]` ?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Test_Tasks\Assets\Delete_Ex\New[*]'
$keys = Get-ChildItem -path:$registryPath
```

## Example Code

```
$keys = "Key", "New Key", "New.Key", "New*"

Write-Host "--LIKE--"
$keys -like "`*"

Write-Host "--MATCH--"
$keys -match "\*"

Write-Host "--RE-MATCH--"
$keys -like "*[*]*"
```

## Results

```
--LIKE--
Key
New Key
New.Key
New*

--MATCH--
New*

--RE-MATCH--
New*
```

## Explanation

The first example is treating the asterisk like a literal; which is interpreted in the like as `-like "*"` (i.e. match anything!)

The second uses the match operator that works a bit more "regex-y" (that's *defintely* a word, honest).

The last one still uses like but by wrapping it in square brackets we are searching for anything that *includes* the asterisk character

More information available on the **[`about_Wildcards`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1)** help pages